# How to save BLOB url from canvas as new document in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, html5-canvas, blob

I'm working on saving HTML5 canvas object to my MongoDB database.

Right now my my code looks like this:

```
startRecording() {

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let recorder = new CanvasRecorder(canvas, {
    disableLogs: false,
    type: 'canvas',
    recorderType: 'CanvasRecorder'
});

// start recording <canvas> drawings
// a few minutes later
recorder.record();

  setTimeout(() => {
    recorder.stop(function(blob) {
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      console.log(url)
      console.log(blob)



        window.open(url)

    })
  }, 10000);
}
```

This is correctly giving me a BLOB URL. How can I save this output to my database - or, how can I convert this into a brand new URL to be used?

I'm using React for frontend and Node.js / Mongo for the backend. It is a completely decoupled application.

Update: I'm trying to save a video thats playing on my canvas element

Comment: You probably should use [`toDataUrl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) instead

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried making an ajax POST to your server with the blob in the post body? I'm not sure why you're making a url out of the blob if you're sending it to the server

Comment: @H.B. I was unable to get that to work because I'm saving a video and not an "image/png" type file.

Comment: @DominicTobias by that do you mean send the blob object to the backend and have the backend do the conversion into a url? I'll absolutely need a url as a part of the output. Thanks for responding!

Comment: The URL is a clientside thing that is generated only for that particular browser session, it's not something you can send to the server and use again. You would need to store the blob in your database and create a URL using javascript for each client if and when they need it. If you don't need the URL anymore for that session you should also call `URL.revokeObjectURL()` on it so that it's not hogging memory. If this is just a static file you could alternatively send the blob to your server and create a physical file from it and send real (non-blob) url back to the client

Comment: What do you want to use the URL for? For a download, to share, to view later?

Comment: [Send the `blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to you server.